# How do i get max salary row , group by country

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

```
------------------------------------------------
country |   salary  |   name    |   adress  
------------------------------------------------
India   |   10000   |   ch1     |   something
japan   |   20000   |   ch2     |   nothing
india   |   25000   |   ch3     |   hjsdj
japan   |   30000   |   ch4     |   hjhjhj
```

I need to get max salary in japan and also in india with adress, name.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? This can easily be solved using window functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a sub-query that returns each country's max salary. Join with that result to get the users with that max salary.

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
join (select country, max(salary) as max_salary
      from tablename group by country) t2
  on t1.country = t2.country and t1.salary = t2.max_salary
```

Will return both users if it's a tie (i.e. several users with same maximum salary.)

Answer (score 0):

If by chance your DBMS supports ROW_NUMBER() OVER() function you may try

```
select * from
  (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY country ORDER BY salary DESC) as rn
    , country, salary as max_salary, name, adress
  from tablename
  ) t
where rn = 1
```

Note, contrary to jarlh's query it will return only one arbitrary row of equal top salaries rows for the country.